# How to extract numbers from price data(object) in a csv, Python Regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm running regression on Python, and when I'm defining variables, the price in the csv file is an object, how can i extract number from the object?

[data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brnfu.png)

x=data_11.drop(['name', 'price'], axis=1).values

y = data_11['price'].values

Answer (score 0):

```
y = data_11['price'].astype(float).values
```